# Replace String between matching multiline String with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have the following configuration file:

```
dependencies:
- name: server2
  version: 1.0.0.0
  repository: "repository2"
- name: server1
  version: 4.3.2.1
  repository: "repository2"
```

I now want to replace the version of server 1 with something like 'newVersion'.

The version is always below the name, I want to replace the version number (4.3.2.1), but I don't know that number, so I have to replace anything that comes between 'version:' and '\n'.

I know that I want to change the version of server1 though.

I tried the following:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/server1\n\s\sversion:/newVersion/}' file.txt
```

I know sed can't 'normally' read multi-lines without the N operator, but it still does not work for me, does anyone could help me here?

Comment: I think `sed -E ':a;N;$!ba; s/(server1[[:blank:]]*\n[[:blank:]]*version:)[^\x0A]*/\1 newVersion/'` will also work, but is certainly less readable than Pesa's solution.

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML. Don't use regex to parse JSON. Don't use regex to parse Yaml.

Comment: @tripleee what would you recommend?

Comment: Quick googling mainly brings up Python scripts for this. There is a Node tool called `yaml-update` in my search results, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `sed` should do:

```
$ sed '/name: server1$/{n;s/version: .*/version: 5.4.3.2/}' data
dependencies:
- name: server2
  version: 1.0.0.0
  repository: "repository2"
- name: server1
  version: 5.4.3.2
  repository: "repository2"
```

Comment: I believe `/name: server1/` should be changed to `/name: server1$/` to make sure the `server1` is only matched at the end of the line (to avoid matching `server 10`, e.g.).

Answer (score 0):

This sed replaces between `name: server1$` and `version:` this: `version: .*` by `version: newVersion`.

```
sed '/name: server1$/,/version: /s/version: .*/version: newVersion/'
```